# JOIN WITH entity.collection Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I've been trying a lot of different things but I can't seem to find a way to JOIN... WITH an entity's attribute as a collection.
Say I have users and contacts. Because of reasons, I want to make a query such as :

```
SELECT c FROM Bundle:Contact c
LEFT JOIN Bundle:User u WITH c.user = u
WHERE c IN u.contacts
```

**I know this query doesn't seem to make any sense, but the actual query I'm working on does :)**

So Doctrine does not accept that query as it expects a SELECT...FROM after the IN.
How do I make a query so that I can check that c belongs to the collection u.contacts? How does one restrain selection according to select in an entity's attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Try MEMBER OF:

```
SELECT c FROM Bundle:Contact c
LEFT JOIN Bundle:User u WITH c.user = u
WHERE c MEMBER OF u.contacts
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to be honest, I have no idea what you are trying to do. I will give you 2 examples, one will probably be what you need or at least give you an idea what to do.

First problem; your WITH and IN conditions doesn't really make much sense for me. If you want to JOIN only some Users, you should do this:

```
//ContactRepository
public function findMeSomething()
{
    $subquery = "SELECT s1.id FROM Bundle:User s1 WHERE ... some condition" ;

    return $this->createQueryBuilder("c")
        ->leftJoin("c.Users", "u", "WITH", "u.id IN ($subquery)"
        ...
```

This would join contact with its users; not all, users would be limited by $subquery.

Second: if you want to limit fetching contacts (primary select), then

```
    $subquery = "SELECT s1.id FROM Bundle:Contact s1 WHERE ... some condition" ;
    ->where("c.id IN ($subquery)"
```

Comment: First, thank you for answering. I have tried using subqueries, but no matter where I place the condition, I always have to use IN (for instance, WHERE c IN u.contacts), which needs a subquery.
Here, User has an attribute contacts which is a collection of contacts. I want the query to limit contacts to these that belong to this collection, having a clause that does not rely on a subquery but a collection.